# Slow query, can I speed it up?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm retrieving images stored as blobs in the database using a python script running on the same server.

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM imagedb_production.imagedb IMAGE 
LEFT JOIN dccms_production.tblmedia MEDIA ON IMAGE.name = MEDIA.name 
LEFT JOIN dccms_production.tblmultimedia CAP ON MEDIA.contentItemID = CAP.contentItemID 
    LIMIT 5000,100;
```

An EXPLAIN returns

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys               key         key_len     ref                                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      IMAGE   index   NULL                        name_idx        767     NULL                                    10145962        Using index
1   SIMPLE      MEDIA   ref     name                        name            63      imagedb_production.IMAGE.name           1   
1   SIMPLE      CAP     eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_contentItemID   PRIMARY         4       dccms_production.MEDIA.contentItemID    1       Using index
```

(Sorry the output looks like crap)

This query takes close to 12 minutes is there any way I can speed this up before going through and tuning the mysql db instance?

Additional information

```
'imagedb', 'CREATE TABLE `imagedb` (
  `multimediaID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumblob,
  `description` longtext,
  `mime_type` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`multimediaID`),
  KEY `name_idx` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2320759 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'


'tblmedia', 'CREATE TABLE `tblmedia` (
  `mediaID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contentItemID` int(11) NOT NULL default ''0'',
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `width` int(11) default NULL,
  `height` int(11) default NULL,
  `file1Size` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `file2Size` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `mediaSlug` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`mediaID`),
  KEY `idx_contentItemID` (`contentItemID`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(20))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=899975 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

'tblmultimedia', 'CREATE TABLE `tblmultimedia` (
  `contentItemID` int(11) NOT NULL default ''0'',
  `caption` text,
  `mimeType` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contentItemID`),
  KEY `idx_contentItemID` (`contentItemID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Do you need all the columns from all the tables involved?  What are the data types of the columns used in the joins?  Any indexes - if yes, have you refreshed the indexes using [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html)

Comment: Great points. Can you also add the output of "show create table" for each table involved?

Comment: 10M rows is not that many. You might be running out of memory or buffer space. If the system is having to go back to the disk a lot, that will really slow things down.

Comment: How much of the time is spent with the query, and how much is spent transmitting the images? You can run "show full status" to see what MySQL is doing at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Added information to the question.

Comment: I do need most of the column data. I wasn't sure if removing the one or two column I don't need would matter compared to the blob I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have 10,000,000 rows with no sorting, I would fix that. Add a default order by clause.

Older versions of MySQL did not take limit clauses into account until much later. I think newer versions do a better job of that. You might want to check into different ways to limit the result set.